# Hive 0.14.0.2.2.4.10-1 : Multi Insert - Empty partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to do a multi-insert using the below query.

```
From kiran.employee_part ep
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept = 'gbm', pspm = 'ajay')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment  where ep.pdept = 'gbm' and ep.pspm = 'ajay'
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept='rw' , pspm='prashanth')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='rw' and ep.pspm='prashanth'
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept='test' , pspm='test')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='test' and ep.pspm='test'
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part partition (pdept='test1' , pspm='test1')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='test1' and ep.pspm='test1';
```

The **select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='test1' and ep.pspm='test1'** query doesn't return any rows as expected. Rest of the select queries retruns few rows. After executing the above queries my entire kiran.employee_ext_part table becomes NULL as show below.

```
hive> select * from employee_ext_part;
OK
employee_ext_part.id    employee_ext_part.name  employee_ext_part.dept  employee_ext_part.skill employee_ext_part.sal   employee_ext_part.mgr   employee_ext_part.spm   employee_ext_part.comment       employee_ext_part.pdept        employee_ext_part.pspm
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    gbm     ajay
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    rw      prashanth
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    test    test
Time taken: 8.116 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

If I comment out the last query and execute it, the table gets populated with the respective values.

```
From kiran.employee_part ep
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept = 'gbm', pspm = 'ajay')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment  where ep.pdept = 'gbm' and ep.pspm = 'ajay'
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept='rw' , pspm='prashanth')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='rw' and ep.pspm='prashanth'
insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
partition (pdept='test' , pspm='test')
select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='test' and ep.pspm='test'
--insert overwrite table kiran.employee_ext_part
--partition (pdept='test1' , pspm='test1')
--select ep.id,ep.name,ep.dept,ep.skill,ep.sal,ep.mgr,ep.spm,ep.comment where ep.pdept='test1' and ep.pspm='test1'
;

hive> select * from employee_ext_part;
OK
employee_ext_part.id    employee_ext_part.name  employee_ext_part.dept  employee_ext_part.skill employee_ext_part.sal   employee_ext_part.mgr   employee_ext_part.spm   employee_ext_part.comment       employee_ext_part.pdept        employee_ext_part.pspm
11    devillers gbm     plsql   1000.0  brijesh ajay            NULL    gbm     ajay
12      fafdu   gbm     plsql   5000.0  kiran   ajay            NULL    gbm     ajay
13      steyn   gbm     ba      10000.0 sudeep  ajay            NULL    gbm     ajay
18      duminy  gbm     hr     100001.0 smith   ajay            NULL    gbm     ajay
15      albe    rw      testing 100.0   venu    prashanth       NULL    rw      prashanth
19      miller  rw      testing 1000.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    rw      prashanth
20      pointin rw      testing 8989.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    rw      prashanth
21      rhodes  rw      tesging 9090.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    rw      prashanth
15      albe    rw      testing 100.0   venu    prashanth       NULL    test    test
19      miller  rw      testing 1000.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    test    test
20      pointin rw      testing 8989.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    test    test
21      rhodes  rw      tesging 9090.0  ram     prashanth       NULL    test    test
Time taken: 0.295 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
```

Can somebody tell me what's going wrong please? Is this how it is supposed to work when we have a query that returns NULL in Multi Insert or am I missing something?

P.S - Sorry for the headers. Not able to align it properly.

Comment: Comment #1: your first script stops abruptly on *insert overwrite* with no *select* afterwards (?!?), but your second scripts shows a *select* commented out. Please make sure that you show the actual scripts that you have run. //// Comment #2: do you use TEZ or MapReduce? //// Comment #3: what about the table structure - Text, AVRO, Sequence, ORC, Parquet? and the column types - String all?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Edited the post. Used MR and the table structure is Text.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not a big fan of multi-tables *Insert*, especially in your case of multi-tables-that-are-all-the-same-table-but-different-partitions.

If you can't fix your script, why don't you try something more straightforward such as...

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode =nonstrict ;

insert overwrite into table KIRAN.EMPLOYEE_EXT_PART
partition (PDEPT, PSPM)
select ID, NAME, DEPT, SKILL, SAL, MGR, SPM, COMMENT,
       PDEPT, PSPM
from KIRAN.EMPLOYEE_PART
--where ....
;
```

Comment: I am well aware of this approach but I am just trying to understand why NULL values. Ideally it shouldn't, right?

Comment: There are hundreds of bugs in each release of Hive, some related to a specific SERDE, some related to a specific feature, some related to a specific execution engine (e.g. TEZ), some related to a specific set of config properties -- and some to a combination of factors. IMHO it makes no sense to try to "understand" an issue that may be specific to your current setup, unless *(a)* you must find a workaround or *(b)* you have the balls to debug the damn thing and contribute a bug fix to Apache.

Comment: Yes, there are many bugs with each release. The point is, if something doesn't work as expected one should make sure that the implementation is not wrong before commiting that it is a bug with the tool itself. That is what I am trying to do.